# How to get select values from ng-bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I have an ng-bootstrap modal on my website, the modal has two `<select>` with dynamic items in it, then the user is able to click two button, one will just close the `modal` and set *Reactive Form* value to `new Date()` but when the user press the other button i have to get the value from both `<select>` and set it as the *Reactive Form* value.

As i'm new to angular, how should i get the values from `<select>` on click?

Here is my Modal:

```
<ng-template #programma let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Scegli un orario</h4>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="close"
      aria-label="Close"
      (click)="quando(true, modal)"
    >
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <select class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary" >
      <option *ngFor="let giorno of giorni" [value]="giorno.time">{{ giorno.formatted }}</option>
    </select>
    <select class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary mt-3">
      <option *ngFor="let ora of ore" [value]="ora">{{ ora }}</option>
    </select>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary"
      (click)="quando(false, modal)"
    >
      Programma
    </button>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-dark"
      (click)="quando(true, modal)"
    >
      Consegna adesso
    </button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

And here is the method quando() which set the value to *Reactive Form*

```
quando(val: boolean, modal?: any): void {
    this.quandoCheck = val;
    if (val) {
      this.checkoutForm.get('spedizione.quando').patchValue(new Date());
    } else {
      // get values from SELECT and set to this.checkoutForm.get('spedizione.quando')
    }

    if (modal){
      modal.close();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> how should i get the values from select input

You can bind a model to the select inputs in two ways:

1. Reactive ( using formControl ):

- In the template:

```
<select [formControl] = "select1Control" ...
```

- In the controller:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComp {
select1Control = new FormControl('');
...
```

- How to get the value :

```
console.log(this.select1Control.value)
```

2. Template driven (using ngModel) :

- In the template:

```
<select [(ngModel)] = "select1" ...
```

- In the controller:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComp {
select1 = ''
...
```

- How to get the value :

```
console.log(this.select1)
```

[Run It On Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqhhgq?file=src/app/modal-basic.ts)

Other options: Using form groups / using refrences .

Ps: Don't forget to import form (or reactiveForm) modules.